# Ansible check host online -> if not online -> start installer

Tags: ansible

I want to create a playbook for Ansible, which will first check if the host is online or not. If host is online - it should abort the execution of playbook or skip tasks/roles, which are defined further down in the playbook. Otherwise it should execute further actions.

What i have now:

```
---
- name: Install nameserver from scratch
  hosts: ns
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    role: BIND
    type: host
    msg: "Successfully installed from scratch"

  tasks:
    - name: Check if host is accessible
      run_once: true
      shell: ping -c 1 -w 2 {{ item }} 2>&1 > /dev/null
      register: online
      delegate_to: localhost
      with_items: "{{  ansible_play_batch }}"
      failed_when: false

- name: Install the role if no respond from host is available
  include_role:
    name: "{{ pl_role }}"
  when: online.results.item.rc !=0  # 1)
  with_items:
    - scratch
    - default
    - bind
    - jabber_notifier
  loop_control:
    loop_var: pl_role
```

1) I know that the results are in the looped var, but how can i get them from there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys, sorry for noise, i've got it working.

Already on the ping stage i can interrupt the further execution of a playbook by assigning to failed_when key the value of "online.rc == 0". So we can make the execution to abort on that stage,

```
- name: Check if host is accessible
  run_once: true
  shell: ping -c 1 -w 2 {{ item }} 2>&1 > /dev/null
  register: online
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_items: "{{  ansible_play_batch }}"
  failed_when: online.rc == 0
```

after this, all other tasks/role actions will be not executed.

```
- name: Install the role if no respond from host is available
  include_role:
    name: "{{ pl_role }}"
  loop:
    - scratch
    - default
    - bind
    - jabber_notifier
  loop_control:
    loop_var: pl_role
```

Cheers